# jQuery code does work after updating

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have page where an instant search results are displaying using PHP & AJAX and `<a>` tag `onclick` from response item, it generate preview of track. Everything is working fine but when I update my jQuery version from `1.7.2` to `1.11.3` or `2.1.4`. It open link instead of generating preview.

My code

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($)
{
    $(".videos .expand-video a.soundcloud").live("click", function(){
            var scURL = $(this).attr("href");
            var scID = $(this).attr("id");
            var embedAudio = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"166\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url="+scURL+"&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false\"></iframe>";
            $("#sc-"+scID).html(embedAudio);
            return false;
    });


    var timer = null;
    $("#keyword").keyup(function()
    {

        if(timer)
        {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
                var sc_keyword = $("#keyword").val();
                var obj = $(this);

                if(sc_keyword != '')
                {
                    $(".ajax_indi").show();
                    var str = $("#fb_expand").serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "fetch.php",
                        data: str,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(htmlresp)
                        {
                            $('#results').html(htmlresp);
                            $(".ajax_indi").hide();
                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Search for your favourite news");
                    $("#keyword").focus();
                }
        }, 1000);

    });

});
</script>
```

I know `.live()` has been removed in version `1.9` onwards. So, I tried to update it to `.on()` but does not done it successfully

What I have tried to update from `.live()` to `.on()` is below

```
$(".videos .expand-video a.soundcloud").on("click", 'a', function(){
        var scURL = $(this).attr("href");
        var scID = $(this).attr("id");
        var embedAudio = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"166\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url="+scURL+"&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false\"></iframe>";
        $("#sc-"+scID).html(embedAudio);
        return false;
});
```

> HTML OUTPUT Response of ajax request

```
<div class="videos" id="sc-80912043">
  <div class="expand-video"> <a class="soundcloud" id="80912043" href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks
/80912043"><span></span> <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000033051760-4ugg0i-large.jpg" width
="120" height="90" title="Play" alt="Play"/> </a> </div>
  <div class="details">
    <h6>DJ MHA - Menu Chad De (MHA Remix)</h6>
    <p class="link">Gangzta Khan</p>
    <p class="desc">DJ MHA - Menu Chad De (MHA Remix)..
Gangzta Khan ..</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="videos" id="sc-24508938">
  <div class="expand-video"> <a class="soundcloud" id="24508938" href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks
/24508938"><span></span> <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000002625883-ve8pmk-large.jpg" width
="120" height="90" title="Play" alt="Play"/> </a> </div>
  <div class="details">
    <h6>Halka Halka Suroor - MHA Mix</h6>
    <p class="link">DJ MHA</p>
    <p class="desc">Yeh Jo Halka Halka Suroor Hai
Direct Download Link:
http://www.djmha.com/get.php?file=Halka_Halka_Suroor_-_MHA_Mix.mp3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="videos" id="sc-65996317">
  <div class="expand-video"> <a class="soundcloud" id="65996317" href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks
/65996317"><span></span> <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000002625883-ve8pmk-large.jpg" width
="120" height="90" title="Play" alt="Play"/> </a> </div>
  <div class="details">
    <h6>Zarina Taylor - (DJ MHA Remix)</h6>
    <p class="link">DJ MHA</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show how you converted to `on()`. The signatures are different for `on()` and `live()` when delegating

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated my answer.

Comment: Where do these elements get inserted? You need to delegate to an element that exists in page permanently

Comment: What exactly does "It does not work" mean?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist search results are display but `onclick` It generate preview of track but after updating jquery. It open link instead of generating preview.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I have updated my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being too specific with your selector before calling `.on()`. The way the function works is you select elements that will always exist on the page, and bind the delegated event handler to those. Since you're replacing the content of the `<div>` elements with class `videos`, your code should be this:

```
$(".videos").on("click", ".expand-video a.soundcloud", function(){
        var scURL = $(this).attr("href");
        var scID = $(this).attr("id");
        var embedAudio = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"166\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url="+scURL+"&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false\"></iframe>";
        $("#sc-"+scID).html(embedAudio);
        return false;
});
```

First, we select the `.videos` elements, then we bind a delegated event handler for `a.soundcloud` elements which are inside a `.expand-video` element (which are in turn inside a `.videos` element). That way, when you update the content of one of those elements in this line - `$("#sc-"+scID).html(embedAudio);` - the delegated event handler still exists.

Comment: Thank you. Your provided code does not work 100% but you show me right direction and the issue is solved with little changes in your code. I'm loading result in `<div id="results">` So I have done little change in first line of your code. Change is `$("#results").on("click", ".videos .expand-video a.soundcloud", function(){`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why this worked in an old version!!!

So just for one video

```
<div class="videos" id="sc-80912043">
  <div class="expand-video"> <a class="soundcloud" id="80912043" href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks
/80912043"><span></span> <img src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000033051760-4ugg0i-large.jpg" width
="120" height="90" title="Play" alt="Play"/> </a> </div>
  <div class="details">
    <h6>DJ MHA - Menu Chad De (MHA Remix)</h6>
    <p class="link">Gangzta Khan</p>
    <p class="desc">DJ MHA - Menu Chad De (MHA Remix)..
Gangzta Khan ..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a problem i have had a few times .on does not act the same as live with the active binding even though it's supposed to...

```
 function gotAJAXResults(){
    $(".videos .expand-video a.soundcloud").unbind("click");
    $(".videos .expand-video a.soundcloud").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var scURL = $(this).attr("href");
          var scID = $(this).attr("id");
          var embedAudio = "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"166\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url="+scURL+"&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false\"></iframe>";
          $("#sc-"+scID).html(embedAudio);
          return false;
    });
}
```

Ok so now your AJAX call becomes

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch.php",
    data: str,
    cache: false,
    success: function(htmlresp)
    {
        $('#results').html(htmlresp);
        gotAJAXResults();
        $(".ajax_indi").hide();
    }
});
```

This method will then force it to bind the event when ajax receives and has inserted them into the page. (DOM scope)

Comment: `live()` is deprecated and removed as of `1.8`. Any solution that uses it is invalid

Comment: And the point i was making is still valid if he was using 1.8 i don't understand how the hell it worked on 1.7 as the DOM element had no id or href attributes.

Comment: @MartinBarker I have tried your answer but does not works for me. I have updated my answer again and added AJAX code too in my question.

Comment: Any errors in you Browsers Javascript Console? and is AJAX working can i access your test system to check it all if so whats the URL?

Comment: @MartinBarker there is nothing `consol.log` link is opening instead of expand and generating preview.

Comment: @Hassaan please use Google Chrome and follow these steps.
Make sure the Page Inspector is open refresh the page click network at the top of the inspector window click XHR 2 lines below the network button. no go to your page and use the ajax enabled part of your site does a page show in the list in the inspector yes or no? if yes is the ajax page?

Comment: @MartinBarker I'm using firebug on firefox 40. Search results are display and It have to generate preview of track when clicked on link specific `<a>` link. Issue is only that when I click on `<a>` tag It open link instead of generating preview.

Comment: @MartinBarker I have posted my complete code in my question. Please have a look on it.

Comment: Oh this is due to the fact that your selector is being fired after the A tags click event. i will update now to show you how to fix that

Comment: Updated End of my answer has an implementation for you

Comment: @MartinBarker you last updated answer seem to work perfectly but it does not. I really don't under what is the issue.

Comment: This seletor `$(".videos .expand-video")` selects a Div not your A link as such id and href attributes do not exist you needed to select the a and since your a links have a class of soundcloud i added that to the selector

Comment: @MartinBarker I am selecting it as you said. Using your latest solution which is like `$(".videos .expand-video a.soundcloud").click(function(e){`

Comment: @Hassaan Yeah thats why it works now before you were not